# Javascript change function triggers tagname

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have working HTML and Javascript code but only for one `select` tag. And the issue is that I need it to cover all `select` tags I have in HTML. So colors in all options should be changed according to its `value` while selecting them.

```html
Some text <select> <option value='red'>wrong option</option> <option value='green'>right option</option> <option value='red'>wrong option</option> </select> some text.<br>
Some text <select> <option value='green'>right option</option> <option value='red'>wrong option</option> <option value='red'>wrong option</option> </select> some text.<br>
Some text <select> <option value='red'>wrong option</option> <option value='red'>wrong option</option> <option value='green'>right option</option> </select> some text.
```

That is only for first element in the `select` array.

```
var select = document.getElementsByTagName('select');

select[0].onchange = function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < select[0].options.length; i++) {
        if(i == select[0].selectedIndex) {
            select[0].style.color = this.value;
        } else {
            select[0].options[i].style.color = 'black';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you will have to loop over `select` and assign listener to all selects.

Second, you should use `this.style.color = this.value;` instead of `select[0].style.color = this.value;`

#### Sample

```js
var select = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
  
function handleChange() {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.options.length; i++) {
    if (i == this.selectedIndex) {
      this.style.color = this.value;

    } else {
      this.options[i]
        .style.color = 'black';
    }
  }
}

for(var i = 0; i< select.length; i++)
  select[i].addEventListener('change', handleChange)
```

```html
Some text
<select>
  <option value='red'>wrong option</option>
  <option value='green'>right option</option>
  <option value='red'>wrong option</option>
</select>some text.
<br>Some text
<select>
  <option value='green'>right option</option>
  <option value='red'>wrong option</option>
  <option value='red'>wrong option</option>
</select>some text.
<br>Some text
<select>
  <option value='red'>wrong option</option>
  <option value='red'>wrong option</option>
  <option value='green'>right option</option>
</select>some text.
```

Comment: Thank's so much! I have tried eventListener function before but got a failure so desided to use foor loop as main solution. Thank's one more time for your efforts)

Answer (score 1):

You're specifically targeting the first `select` element with `select[0]`. If you want to apply this to *all* of them, you'll need a loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < select.length; i++) {
  select[i].onchange = function() { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.forEach`

```
var select = document.getElementsByTagName('select');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(select, function (selectElement) {
    selectElement.onchange = function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < select[0].options.length; i++) {
            if (i == select[0].selectedIndex) {
                selectElement.style.color = this.value;

            } else {
                selectElement.options[i]
                        .style.color = 'black';
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: I didn't know this way of solving such issues before. Thank you for your great answer. I will take it into account)